# GAE Users service returns xml for user nickname property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid, federated-identity

I have an application that uses the GAE users service and fedarated login.

Latetly for one user I get an xml feed in the nickname property.

For **all the other fields** the data is ok

In details:

**My register handler**:

```
class RegisterPersonHandler(UserPageHandler):

    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if not user:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri), abort=True)
            return
        person = Person.get_or_insert(user.user_id())
        if not self._register(person, user):
            logging.warning('Warning registration failed')
            return
        self.redirect("/")

    def post(self):
        self.view("No reason to be here Mr Jiggles ;-)")
        return

    @ndb.transactional()
    def _register(self, person, user):
        ''' Registration process happens here
        '''
        # check if the person has info and if not create it
        info = PersonInfo.query(ancestor=person.key).get()
        if not info:
            info = PersonInfo(id=user.user_id(), parent=person.key)
            info.nick_name = user.nickname()
            info.email = user.email()
            info.put()
        return True
```

At the **nickname** field I get the following **string**:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=[id_of_the_user]
```

Opening that url in my browser lets me download an **xml** with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrds:XRDS xmlns:xrds="xri://$xrds" xmlns="xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)">
<XRD>
<Service priority="0">
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon</Type>
<Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
<URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud</URI>
</Service>
<Service priority="10">
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon</Type>
<Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
<URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=mail</URI>
</Service>
<Service priority="10">
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon</Type>
<Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
<URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=gmail.com</URI>
</Service>
<Service priority="10">
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon</Type>
<Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
<URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=googlemail.com</URI>
</Service>
<Service priority="10">
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon</Type>
<Type>http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/icon</Type>
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0</Type>
<URI>https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=profiles</URI>
</Service>
</XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Because this is getting nowhere, I would like to at least know:

Can I trust the nickname propery to return a string with a useable nickname for the user? 
I have already figured out that this property imposes a risk if you want to expose it to public data, due to most of the cases beeing the "username" or email address...

BTW

From the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass#User_user_id)

> nickname() Returns the "nickname" of the user, a displayable name. For
>   Google Accounts users, the nickname is either the "name" portion of
>   the user's email address if the address is in the same domain as the
>   application, or the user's full email address otherwise. For OpenID
>   users, the nickname is the OpenID identifier.

and a bit [later](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass#User_email)

> email() Returns the email address of the user. If you use OpenID, you
>   should not rely on this email address to be correct. Applications
>   should use nickname for displayable names.